# Не разберусь с модулем pip

Tags: python

Я только начал изучать питон. Хотел установить Фласк. Рекомендовали через модуль pip, в командной строке питон пишет Invalid Syntax. Пробовал через файл get-pip.py, тоже самое. Не пойму как проверить есть pip или нет. Вроде версия питон 3.6, то есть модуль должен быть встроен.

Comment: `в командной строке питон пишет Invalid Syntax` - нужно просто в cmd или powershell запускать, а не в самом python